# Ignoring the NaN rows when collapsing data by group_by in Pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by

I would like to collapse a dataset using groupby and agg and I want to preserve the NaN values as separate rows without collapsing. For example, the initial data is:

```
  mydata = {'category' : [np.NaN, np.NaN, "a", "b", "b", "c"],'category2' : ["f", "f", "r", "h", "h", "j"], 'value' : ['12', '11', '10', '13', '15', '11']}
df = pd.DataFrame(mydata, columns=['category','category2','value'])

df=df.groupby(['category','category2'],  dropna=False 
).agg({'value':'max'})

    category    category2   value
0   NaN              f       12
1   NaN              f       11
2   a                r       10
3   b                h       13
4   b                h       15
5   c                j       11
```

Current output:

```
  category  category2   value
0   NaN        f          12
1   a          r          10
2   b          h          15
3   c          j          11
```

Desired output:

```
  category  category2   value
0   NaN        f          12
1   NaN        f          11
2   a          r          10
3   b          h          15
4   c          j          11
```

Is there a way to do this with `group_by`, other than splitting the dataframe to two NaN and non-NaN dataframes?

Comment: Keep in mind that `NaN` is an outdated hack to store missing values in certain numerical-valued columns. Unless you are performing specific kinds of numerical computations, you should treat them generally as "null" values, as in SQL `NULL` or R `NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concat rows of both cases (with `NaN` values and aggregated without `NaN`):

```
df = pd.concat([df[df['category'].isna()],
                df.groupby(['category','category2'])
               .agg({'value':'max'}).reset_index()])
```

---

```
  category category2 value
0      NaN         f    12
1      NaN         f    11
0        a         r    10
1        b         h    15
2        c         j    11
```